# F-2 visa for a dependent before F-1 status is obtained by a Canadian citizen

Tags: usa, student-visa, dependent-visa, canadian-citizens

[Travel.state.gov](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/study/student-visa.html#spouse) mentions for applying an F-2 visa

> You must provide a copy of your F-1 or M-1 visa and provide proof of relationship. You must provide a copy of your F-1 or M-1 visa and provide proof of relationship.

A Canadian citizen plans to attend a US institution and their spouse is a visa-required national. I-20 forms have been issued for both the principal and the dependent.

Can the spouse apply and obtain an F-2 visa before the Canadian citizen obtains F-1 status at a port of entry?

If not, is visiting the US before the commencement of studies solely to obtain the F-1 status (then immediately return to Canada) allowed (or does CBP even track this)?

Comment: A Canadian citizen who doesn't have an F-1 visa, goes to the border, and obtains F-1 status there still doesn't have an F-1 visa.  Does the application allow an exception for Canadians to show F-1 status through some means other than a copy of an F-1 visa?  If not, the Canadian may need to get a visa at a US consulate.

Comment: @phoog I assume an I-94 would be enough?

Comment: I want to note that this is discussed in relation to TN/TD in [9 FAM 402.17-6](https://fam.state.gov/FAM/09FAM/09FAM040217.html#M402_17_6)(a)(1-2). It says that although Canadian citizens don't need most types of nonimmigrant visas, a qualified applicant can still be issued one. It also mentions one case for needing to issue a TN visa to a Canadian citizen is to travel together with a non-Canadian TD dependent who needs a visa. It doesn't address F1/F2 but the same reasoning would suggest that the Canadian could get an F1 visa so their spouse can get an F2 visa and travel at the same time.

Comment: @user102008 Thanks a lot! From the wording (they mentioned "living in a third country"), I was wondering if it is possible to apply for status for dependents at port of entry also?

Comment: @xngtng: No. A non-Canadian citizen need a visa to seek entry to the US. US visas can only be obtained at US consulates; never at the port of entry.